# Loop through complex array of POST'ed form fields

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a `View` that renders HTML dynamically. It ends up looking like this:

```
<form asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Save">
    <!-- Location widget class -->
    <input name="widgets[0].Name" />
    <input name="widgets[0].Type" value="Location" />
    <input name="widgets[0].Location" />

    <!-- Rating widget class -->
    <input name="widgets[1].Name" />
    <input name="widgets[1].Type" value="Rating" />
    <input name="widgets[1].Rating" />
    <input name="widgets[1].Remark" />

    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Each "widget" is defined in a separate class, like this:
*(The poperties `Name` and `Type` are defined in the parent `Widget` class)*

```
public class Location : Widget
{
    public string Location {get;set;}
}

public class Rating : Widget
{
    public string Rating {get;set;}
    public string Remark {get;set;}
}
```

The problem I have is that I have to `POST` this form back to my controller. In there I want to be able to do something like this:

```
public IActionResult Save()
{
    var req = HttpContext.Request;

    foreach(var widget in req.widgets)
    {
        if(widget.Type == "Location") { 
            ... 
        }
        else if(widget.Type == "Rating") { 
            ... 
        }
        // etc.
    }
}
```

It seems like I cannot simply read out the properties like that from the `HttpContext.Request` object.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Probably with a custom model binder. Look up model binding polymorphism

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read form fields as KeyValuePairs if you add an IFormCollection object to the params:

```
public IActionResult Save(IFormCollection formCollection)
```

Regarding your concrete problem, I believe that you can do as following:

I have not tested the following code, but I am almost certain that it works!

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Save(List<Widget> widgets)
{
    for(var i = 0; i < widgets.Count; i++)
    {
        if(widgets[i].Type == "Location") { 
            var locationObj = new Location();
            await TryUpdateModelAsync(locationObj, $"widgets[{i}]");
            //Do whatever you want with the object.
        }
        else if(widgets[i].Type == "Rating") { 
            var ratingObj = new Rating();
            await TryUpdateModelAsync(ratingObj, $"widgets[{i}]");
            //Do whatever you want with the object. 
        }
        // etc.
    }
    ...
}
```

Please, let me know if it helped!